# Rails Bundler gems install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I´m trying to run my Ruby on Rails project on my webserver, I´ve got this message from passenger:

```
Error message:
    Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

this happens when I´m trying install budle in SSH.

```
passenger@web2:/var/www/clients/client11/web100/web$ bundle install .bundle
/home/passenger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/settings.rb:101:in `initialize': Permission denied - /var/www/clients/client11/web100/web/.bundle/config (Errno::EACCES)
        from /home/passenger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/settings.rb:101:in `open'
        from /home/passenger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/settings.rb:101:in `set_key'
        from /home/passenger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/settings.rb:15:in `[]='
        from /home/passenger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/cli.rb:211:in `install'
        from /home/passenger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from /home/passenger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from /home/passenger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
        from /home/passenger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
        from /home/passenger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/passenger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from /home/passenger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

or when i try

```
passenger@web2:/var/www/clients/client11/web100/web$ bundle install
Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org/

Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /var/www/clients/client11/web100/web/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/cache
An error occured while installing rake (0.9.2.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '0.9.2.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

but web is coded in ruby1.9.3
i tried install rake manually as suggested

```
passenger@web2:/var/www/clients/client11/web100/web$ gem install rake -v '0.9.2.2'
Fetching: rake-0.9.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rake-0.9.2.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rake-0.9.2.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for rake-0.9.2.2...
passenger@web2:/var/www/clients/client11/web100/web$ bundle install             Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org/

Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /var/www/clients/client11/web100/web/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/cache
An error occured while installing rake (0.9.2.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '0.9.2.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Have you tried running `gem install rake`? Is rake in your Gemile?

Comment: yes, I´ve edited my post.
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
bundler (1.0.21)
rake (0.9.2.2)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have wrong BUNDLE_PATH value.

Check this article, may be it'll help you: http://blog.ninjahideout.com/posts/the-path-to-better-rvm-and-passenger-integration

Comment: can you be more specific please?

Comment: Ok, the last output is under rvm session, right?
/var/www/clients/client11/web100/web/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/cache — this path seems very strange, why not a /home/passenger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/? o_O
It seems that bundler tries to install all the gems locally, is it ok?(It installs all the gems into rvm folder if nothing special has set)
Moreover bundler will write a Gemfile.lock locally, do current user have permissions to create such file?

Comment: there is propably problem with permissions. I´m trying to install my rails app to ISPConfig managed folder, apache is running under www-data, passenger is running under passenger user, but its said something about user nobody:nogroup.

`web100/web/ drwxr-xr-x 3 web100 client11 4096 Feb  3 19:05 bundler`


`/home/passenger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /var/www/clients/client11/web100/web/bundler (Errno::EACCES)`

Comment: You should install your bundles under passenger session, at least client11 should be in passenger group ( not sure about passenger group, check it at /home/passenger/.rvm/ folder ). As I said earlier bundler tries to write .lock file in current folder, so current user should have write permissions in this folder. You're right that's a permissions trouble

Comment: thanks for help, sorry for late answer, I somehow managed to get `Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.` but Im still having problem on my website `Error message:
    Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)` even if `passenger@web2:/var/www/clients/client11/web100/web$ bundle show rake
/home/passenger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@imintest/gems/rake-0.9.2.2
` seems to be ok :/

Comment: the link is down :(